# how to insert list of elements into list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have one list of elements and another list of dictionaries and i want to insert list of elements into each dictionary of list

```
list_elem = [1,2,3]

dict_ele = [{"Name":"Madhu","Age":25},{"Name":"Raju","Age:24},{""Name":"Mani","Age":12}],
```

OUTPUT As:

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"Madhu","Age":25},{"ID":2,"Name":"Raju","Age:24},{"ID":3,"Name":"Mani","Age":12}]
```

I have tried this way :

```
dit = [{"id":item[0]} for item in zip(sam)]
# [{"id":1,"id":2,"id":3}]
dic1 = list(zip(dit,data))
print(dic1)
# [({"id":1},{{"Name":"Madhu","Age":25}},{"id":2},{"Name":"Raju","Age:24},{"id":3},{""Name":"Mani","Age":12})]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: `[{'ID': i, **d} for i, d in zip(list_elem, dict_elem)]`

Comment: Are you sure that *dict_ele* really looks like that? It's syntactically correct but almost certainly not what was intended

Comment: @deceze why posting it as a comment and not as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption here that the OP's original question has a typo in the definition of *dict_ele* and also that *list_elem* isn't really necessary.

```
dict_ele = [{"Name":"Madhu","Age":25},{"Name":"Raju","Age":24},{"Name":"Mani","Age":12}]

dit = [{'ID': id_, **d} for id_, d in enumerate(dict_ele, 1)]

print(dit)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Madhu', 'Age': 25}, {'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Raju', 'Age': 24}, {'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Mani', 'Age': 12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_ele = [{"Name":"Madhu","Age":25},{"Name":"Raju","Age":24},{"Name":"Mani","Age":12}]
list_elem = [1,2,3]

[{'ID': id, **_dict} for id, _dict in zip(list_elem, dict_ele)]
```

```
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Madhu', 'Age': 25}, {'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Raju', 'Age': 24}, {'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Mani', 'Age': 12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `r = [{'id':e[0], **e[1]} for e in zip(list_elem, dict_ele)]`